# In DraftJs How to re adjust the cursor after setting the state via decorator and strategy?

Tags: draftjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

Problem: Loses focus when selected the hash tag.
Example: type #on and select any tag the editor is losing the focus.
In above codepen: how can I add/retain cursor after the hash tag?

Following this article
https://bigbite.net/2017/12/13/building-editor-draft-js-react/
Code from this article.
https://codepen.io/bigbite/pen/gXNOvz

I've to add that in my own use case.

UC: While editing the content in editor when user presses the key combination then show a dropdown, which will contain the custom react component name, and user will be able to select the custom component and it will add that component via decorator and strategy.

It has been achieved but the editor loses its focus at the same time.

I can achieve the focus via **ref** `this.editor.focus()` but shows the cursor at the start of the editor.

```
const addEntityAndComponent = (editorState, content) => {
  const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
  const selection = editorState.getSelection();

  const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(content, 'IMMUTABLE', { content });
  const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
  const newContentState = Modifier.insertText(contentStateWithEntity, selection, content, null, entityKey);

  const newEditorState = EditorState.push(editorState, newContentState);

  return EditorState.forceSelection(newEditorState, newContentState.getSelectionAfter());
};
```

I'm using the lib to achieve the functionality.

https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/

Here is my code.
https://github.com/iozeey/react-draft-wysiwyg-custom-component

Hope it will be helpful.

Followed this doc.
https://draftjs.org/docs/advanced-topics-managing-focus

Tried solution from here but did not work.

https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-editor-state#movefocustoend

Answer (score 0):

I was using this package.

https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/master/src/Editor/index.js#L348

My solution was to reset the cursor position after focusing the editor.

```
focus() {
    const se = this.state.editorState.getSelection();
    this.editor.focus();
    this.setState({
      editorState: EditorState.forceSelection(this.state.editorState, se),
    });
  }
```